# How does npm error affect old git commits?

Tags: npm, node-modules, create-react-app

In my **create-react-app** project I've installed many node packages via npm. Every time, I've used `npm install --save` to update `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and then committed the changes to `git`.

Recently, something caused a previously-working npm module to fail. Since I couldn't find the cause, I tried removed and reinstalled all dependencies like this:

```
    rm -rf node_modules/
    npm install
```

However, the same module still fails, even when I switch back to older commits and repeat the commands above!

Since the problem can't be in the committed code itself (which is running fine on another machine), the problem must be somewhere else such as in the `create-react-app` development server or the `/node_modules`.

*How can I reset my work to a working state, given that everything is in git and was working before?*

**UPDATE:**

My answer below turned out to be only partly right. npm did install a newer version of the package, but that was not actually the problem after all. The true fix was realising that my data (from my database) was corrupt, so returning to prior "working version" made no difference until I fixed my data!

Comment: Note that *nothing* you do can ever change *any* existing Git commit. But Git commits are identified by hash ID, not by branch names—you *can* change which hash ID some branch name identifies. As you found, the problem had nothing to do with Git.

Comment: @torek Yes the code in old commits doesn't change, but the behaviour of that code **can** change if the environment changes. So my question is mostly about node and npm, but I wrote about git for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As mentioned in the updated question, this answer did not actually solve my problem after all. Messing around with the npm modules did fix something, but it soon started failing again, so the fix was incomplete.

**UPDATE 2**: There was also a problem in the data I was passing from my database to the module! That data is not stored in `git`, so fiddling with `npm` modules and `git` had no power.

---

It seems that the problem was in the npm versioning! Since my `package.json` listed `somepackage@^6.0.0`, running `npm install` fetched the latest version (which had the bug).

Hence, my old working commits that referenced `somepackage@^6.0.0` still actually installed the new faulty version when re-installed from scratch.

The solution was to edit `package.json` and change `somepackage@^6.0.0` to `somepackage@6.0.0`(exact match without `^`)